# GDB fails to run program due to KERNELBASE.dll error

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb

I've only started getting this problem recently, and I have no idea when it started occuring/what causes it.

I have this simple test program here:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

but when I try to run it normally, it creates a stackdump.

```
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
00CBC498  6101D93A (00000198, 0000EA60, 000000A4, 00CBC508)
00CBC5C8  610E2F3F (00000000, 60FC04E8, 00CBC658, 7794ABEE)
```

When I try to run it in GDB, however, it just plain fails to do so.

```
gdb: unknown target exception 0x406d1388 at 0x778edae8

Program received signal ?, Unknown signal.
0x778edae8 in RaiseException ()
   from /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/KERNELBASE.dll
(gdb) n
Single stepping until exit from function RaiseException,
which has no line number information.
[Thread 14880.0x11ac exited with code 1080890248]
[Thread 14880.0x3fd8 exited with code 1080890248]
[Thread 14880.0x3b24 exited with code 1080890248]
[Inferior 1 (process 14880) exited with code 010033211610]
```

This is how my compiler's set up:

```
g++ -g -std=c++1y -Wall -c main.cpp -o main.o main.cpp compiled... 
g++ -g -std=c++1y -Wall -o a main.o Successfully compiled!
```

Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong here?
The platform I'm using is Windows, and I'm using Cygwin as my development environment.

OF NOTE: I still get the aforementioned GDB error no matter what I have in main.cpp.

ALSO OF NOTE: Here are the additional files in the a.exe executable:
[image]

I formerly needed `cygboost_filesystem.dll` to get boost_filesystem to work, and I need `libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll` and `libstdc++6` because it won't work without them.

Comment: What if you remove the function body leaving just return 0?

Comment: @where_is_tftp No dice- it still gives the same result.

Comment: and if you remove boost include and namespace definition and leave just #include <iostream> int main()
{
    return 0;
}

Comment: Even then, it still gives the same error.

Comment: Good. Now we know the problem is run time related. What if you remove linking to boost "-lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -L/usr/local/boost_1_61_0/boost/filesystem" and inclusion of boost folder -I/usr/local/boost_1_61_0.

Comment: My compiler setup is about as barebones as it can get now: `g++ -g -std=c++1y -Wall  -c main.cpp -o main.o
main.cpp compiled...
g++ -g -std=c++1y -Wall  -o a main.o
Successfully compiled!
` yet it still gives the error.

Comment: You mean you get this "Stack trace:..." when you execute the binary? (BTW: In this case it would be useful to limit problem statement to above program.)

Comment: Yeah. No clue what causes it, but it happens.

Comment: Make sure you have single cygwin session opened.

Answer (score 1):

Update gdb to the 7.11.1-1 experimental release version.

[Details of GDB bug](https://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin@cygwin.com/msg149735.html)